# C# Clearing Array not clearing not sure why

Tags: c#, arrays

I wrote this program using Arrays in C#. It's homework. I pretty much have everything written in the program but I am stuck on clearing the array. I thought I had it but I don't understand where it's not working.

The program is pretty straightforward. The user enters a score and hits the "add" button. Then the user can enter more scores (anything 0 to 100). If the user chooses "Display" the program will sort the entered scores and display them in a messagebox (done)
if the user presses the "Clear Scores" button the program should clear out the scores. I have it written to clear the text boxes, and I also wrote in there "Scores.Clear();" (Scores being the name of my list array) and then I returned the focus back to my scores entry text box so the user can enter another score.

The book I am using simply says to clear type NameOfList.Clear(); so I'm stuck on why it's not clearing. I can tell it isn't because if I type more scores it will add the total instead of restarting.

Here is my full program code. My clear starts about halfway down.

Thank you in advance.

```
{
public partial class frmScoreCalculator : Form
{
    //declare a list array for scores
    List<int> Scores = new List<int>();

    //set total and average to 0 
    int Total = 0;
    decimal Average = 0;


    public frmScoreCalculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //calculate the average by dividing the sum by the number of entries
    private decimal CalculateAverage(int sum, int n)
    {
        Average = sum / n;

        return Average;
    }
    private void frmScoreCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //closes the program. Escape key will also close the program
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    //clears the text boxes, clears the array, returns focus back to the score text box like a boss.
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtScore.Text = "";
        txtCount.Text = "";
        txtTotal.Text = "";
        txtAverage.Text = "";
        Scores.Clear();
        txtScore.Focus();
    }

    //makes sure the score is within the valid range, calculates the average, adds to the number of
    //scores entered, and adds to the total
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtScore.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            txtScore.Focus();
            return;
        }


        int Score = int.Parse(txtScore.Text);

        if (Score > 0 && Score < 100)
        {
            Scores.Add(Score);

            Total += Score;
            txtTotal.Text = Total.ToString();

            txtCount.Text = Scores.Count.ToString();

            Average = CalculateAverage(Total, Scores.Count);
            txtAverage.Text = Average.ToString();

            txtScore.Text = string.Empty;
            txtScore.Focus();

        }

        // if number is not valid, ask user for valid number
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 0 and 100.", "ENTRY ERROR, DO IT RIGHT!");

        }

        // returns focus to txtNumber
        txtScore.Focus();
        txtScore.Text = "";
    }

    //display button
    private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sorts the scores low to high
        Scores.Sort();

        //displays scores in message box
        string DisplayString = "Sorted Scores :\n\n";

        foreach (int i in Scores)
        {
            DisplayString += i.ToString() + "\n";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(DisplayString);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't appear to have zeroed `Total` when you clear the array.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you! I just caught that as well when I read through the code. I feel like an idiot for not catching that before posting.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Post that as an answer and I'll accept it if you want the points. Thanks again.

Comment: How to spot an obvious problem: post it to a forum ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to zero the variable `Total` at the same time as clearing the array.